# Deleting from Dataset

Tags: vb.net

I have a Data set filling by textboxes and combo boxes and I'm also showing them in a grid as the user hit the apply button. I also have a link delete button. what i want to do is when i hit the delete button I want to delete that particular record but my code deletes them all.

```
Protected Sub gvPlotFilePaymentVouCherDetail_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles gvPlotFilePaymentVouCherDetail.RowDeleting
        Dim dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails As DataSet
        dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails = Session("dataset")
        Dim cid As String = gvPlotFilePaymentVouCherDetail.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Values(0).ToString
        dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails.Tables(0).Rows.Clear()
        gvPlotFilePaymentVouCherDetail.DataSource = dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails.Tables(0).DefaultView
        gvPlotFilePaymentVouCherDetail.DataBind()
        Session("dataset") = dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails
    End Sub
```

This is how it deletes all the records.

Comment: why are you getting all the records again? you don't seem to be updating the dataset in session to hold the new values from the DB because you clear the records and then assign it back to Session. How do you setup your dataset? you need to find the row you are wanting to delete in the dataset from the dataset using the GridViewDeleteEventArgs and then update the database to delete that record and finally assign the dataset to session

Comment: Your code doesn't delete anything. What it's doing is removing every row in the `DataTable`. What you need to do is delete the specific row that is bound to the grid row that the user requested be deleted. With a `DataTable`, removing and deleting are two different things. Removing takes the row out of the `DataTable` like is was never added, which has no effect on the database. Deleting leaves the row in the `DataTable` but flags it as `Deleted`. When you then use a data adapter to save the changes from the `DataTable` to the database, the corresponding row will be deleted from the database.

Comment: You'r not getting it.

Comment: the Data is not saved in the database yet.

Comment: it is in a data set waiting for me to click the save button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails.Tables(0).Rows.Clear()
```

with

```
dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails.Tables(0).Rows.Remove( _ 
dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails.Tables(0).Select("column_name = '" & cid & "'")(0))
```

so it actually only removes the row you want instead of everything... of course set the appropriate 'column_name'